# Gutenberg Modify core taxonomy panel element via wp.hooks.addFilter

Tags: javascript, taxonomy, block-editor

I’ve researched modifying an existing editor element… and there’s little out there. But I did get a good reply at Github that pointed me to this:
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/editor/src/components/post-taxonomies#custom-taxonomy-selector

And apparently the taxonomy panel is filterable via `wp.hooks.addFilter`. That’s a great start! I’ve been able to use that code snippet to mock up some dummy code that replaces the taxonomy panel with a Dashicon.

```
(function ( hooks, editor, components, i18n, element, compose ) {

    var el = wp.element.createElement;
    var Dashicon = wp.components.Dashicon;

    function CustomizeTaxonomySelector( OriginalComponent ) {

        return function( props ) { 

            if ( RB4Tl18n.radio_taxonomies.indexOf( props.slug ) ) { 

                var testprops = { className: 'bacon-class', icon: 'admin-users' };

                return el( 
                    Dashicon,
                    testprops 
                );

            } else {
                return el(
                    OriginalComponent,
                    props
                );
            }
        }
    };

    wp.hooks.addFilter(
        'editor.PostTaxonomyType',
        'RB4T',
        CustomizeTaxonomySelector
    );

} )( window.wp.hooks, window.wp.editor, window.wp.components, window.wp.i18n, window.wp.element, window.wp.compose )
```

Obviously, this isn’t very useful, but I had to start somewhere. So my question is, is it possible to take the incoming `OriginalComponent` function and modify it’s output? I know how to do this with a PHP filter, but in this case `OriginalComponent` is the `HierarchicalTermSelector` react function and I don’t know how to modify what it renders and I think I’m missing the vocabulary to search successfully.

In my use case all the data would be pretty much the same (I need all the terms listed) except that I want to switch the `<input type="checkbox">` to `<input type="radio">`. Or do I have to copy and write my own version of the `HierarchicalTermSelector` element?

Comment: Why do you want the input be changed to `radio` type? Is it because you're going to allow only one selection? Or is it just for a better UI?

Comment: It's to limit the input to a singular option. I'm the author of the plugin [Radio Buttons for Taxonomies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/), but I haven't been able to get this working in Gutenberg.

Comment: I see. So it's pretty easy to *extend* the `OriginalComponent`, but I think your best option would be to copy the `HierarchicalTermSelector` *component* and return it - instead of the `OriginalComponent` - from the filter callback (`CustomizeTaxonomySelector`).

Comment: How do you extend the `OriginalComponent`? I don't know how to do that in React. But as far as I can tell, `OriginalCompnent` already _is_ `HierarchicalTermSelector`, at least when the taxonomy is hierarchical.

Comment: Yes, it is. But check my answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [your plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/) handles both hierarchical and non-hierarchical taxonomies, then I think it might be a better option to *copy* the [`HierarchicalTermSelector`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/editor/src/components/post-taxonomies/hierarchical-term-selector.js) component, and return the copy from the `CustomizeTaxonomySelector` function.

And you can see how I did it [here](https://github.com/5ally/my-term-selector) — **Updated to use the [JavaScript Build Setup](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/javascript/js-build-setup/) which makes things like transpilation *super easy***.

The plugin (or the JavaScript stuff) is not perfect, but it should be good enough as a starting point. And you'd see something like these:

[image]

PS: In the demo, the category "Test" and tag "Test" share the same name, but they're of a different taxonomy. And the same goes to the category "Test 2" and tag "Test 2".

Comment: Not sure if you've tried the sample plugin, but you should know that I've revised it - the version is now `20190402.2` - it was initially `20190402.1`.

Comment: Just getting around to looking today. This is awesome! Thank you! I was hoping to avoid completely copying the element/component but there doesn't appear to be any way around it. I've got to read through it a few more times though... React is still too new to me. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! And I've put the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/5ally/wpse-332513) - if you would like me to update the link in the answer, let me know. :) And yes, you could do: `return _element.createElement( class extends OriginalComponent { ... }, props )`, but you'd need to write all the logic when a term is selected, added, deleted, etc.; so that's why I thought copying is the best option *in your case* for the time being.

Comment: Btw, I'm pretty much new to React, too! So let's learn together? :p

Comment: You're new to React!? You could have fooled me! :) My .org plugins are always low in priority, but I hope to get this one updated finally now with the code you've provided. The biggest thing I wasn't clear on was some of the name replacements you mentioned in the readme. And I need to set up a system for transpiling.

Comment: That (name thing) is something I'm not sure how to explain, but basically, you should not re-include the WordPress packages (e.g. `@wordpress/i18n`) in your project *build*; instead, just use the ones referenced by the global `wp` object (e.g. `wp.i18n`). You can check the current WordPress JavaScript packages [here](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/packages/) - and the statement there which says, "*JavaScript packages are available as a registered script in WordPress and can be accessed using the `wp` global variable.*" might help you?

Comment: "system for transpiling" - actually WordPress already implemented such a system! Check [this repo](https://github.com/5ally/my-term-selector). :)

Comment: Thanks Sally. I did find that and have made some decent progress, but there are still some issues concerning setting state and saving data that I have to work out.